# How to query a MySQL database via python using peewee/mysqldb?

Tags: python, mysql, ios, peewee

I'm creating an iOS client for App.net and I'm attempting to setup a push notification server. Currently my app can add a user's App.net account id (a string of numbers) and a APNS device token to a MySQL database on my server. It can also remove this data. I've adapted code from these two tutorials:

- [How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App - raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)
- [Apple Push Notification Services in iOS 6 Tutorial: Part 1/2 - raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

In addition, I've adapted [this awesome python script](https://github.com/bryanjclark/Blixt-Server?files=1) to listen in to App.net's App Stream API.

My python is horrendous, as is my MySQL knowledge. What I'm trying to do is access the APNS device token for the accounts I need to notify. My database table has two fields/columns for each entry, one for user_id and a one for device_token. I'm not sure of the terminology, please let me know if I can clarify this.

I've been trying to use [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to read from the database but I'm in way over my head. This is a test script with placeholder `user_id`:

```
import logging
from pprint import pprint

import peewee
from peewee import *

db = peewee.MySQLDatabase("...", host="localhost", user="...", passwd="...")

class MySQLModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Active_Users(MySQLModel):
    user_id = peewee.CharField(primary_key=True)
    device_token = peewee.CharField()

db.connect()

# This is the placeholder user_id
userID = '1234' 

token = Active_Users.select().where(Active_Users.user_id == userID)
pprint(token)
```

This then prints out:

```
<class '__main__.User'> SELECT t1.`id`, t1.`user_id`, t1.`device_token` FROM `user` AS t1 WHERE (t1.`user_id` = %s) [u'1234']
```

If the code didn't make it clear, I'm trying to query the database for the row with the `user_id` of '`1234`' and I want to store the `device_token` of the same row (again, probably the wrong terminology) into a variable that I can use when I send the push notification later on in the script.

How do I correctly return the device_token? Also, would it be easier to forgo peewee and simply query the database using python-mysqldb? If that is the case, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `User.select().where(User.user_id == userID)` returns a `User` object but you are assigning it to a variable called `token` as you're expecting just the `device_token`.

Your assignment should be this:

```
matching_users = Active_Users.select().where(Active_Users.user_id == userID) # returns an array of matching users even if there's just one
if matching_users is not None:
    token = matching_users[0].device_token
```

Comment: Awesome, and thanks for such a quick reply. I made some edits because it turns out `class User(ActiveUsers)...` was then querying a table called 'users' when in fact my table is called 'active_users'. Now with your code I'm properly querying my table but I'm receiving this output now: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'")` I think this might have something to do with not having a column in my table named '`id`'. Any thoughts?

Comment: `Unknown column` means that columns exist, so you're right. Add an `id` column to your table.

Comment: I got it working! I just needed to set my one of the fields to be the primary_key. I'm not quite sure what that means but it prints out my token! I've updated the line 'user_id = peewee.Charfield()' to be 'user_id = peewee.Charfield(primary_key=True)`. Thanks for the help!